# How to send message to UIViewController

Tags: ios, touch, transparent

I have a problem as following, I've developed a ios app, to be concice , It has a `UIViewController` as parent, also it has a button , and the `UIViewController` popup a transparent `UIView` as a mask. When I click on the `UIView`(exactly within the underlying button boundary ) , the button could not receive any event(such as "`touch up inside"`), how could the button get the "`touch up inside"` event from transparent the `UIView` which is above the `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible directly as the event triggered will not be for the button as button is not visible
(ie. another View is completly covering the button and is blocking the interaction with the user).
But i can give u a work around.

1.Declare a Bool Variable in your UIViewController
2.Implement the touches methods as shown below

```
- (void)touchesBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, p) && !boolVariable) {
    boolVariable = YES;
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:self.view];

//  If the below condition is true then it mean there the user tapped on the same location as that of button..(touchesEnded and touchesCanceled was not called) so the event is just like touchUpInside
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, p) && boolVariable) {
      boolVariable = NO;
      [Here you can call the method which you wanted to call on touchUpInside of the button];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
boolVariable = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCanceled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
boolVariable = NO;
}
```

I was not able to test the able code on Xcode but i think it will work..
Note: The frame of the button should be with respect to the UIViewController.
Hope this helps u out :)

Comment: However , I cant get any touche event in this `UIViewController`.

Comment: This did not exactly solve my problem but helped me solve it myself so +1 from my side :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` instances, do not listen for touches. In order to get callbacks for events such as "touch up inside" are only sent to subclasses of `UIControl`

The most basic concrete subclass is [`UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

Without code or more details about your app's setup, it's difficult to give better advice.

Comment: If `UIView` couldn't receive "touch up inside" event , I wanna construct a fake "touch up inside" event and send to the underlying `UIViewController` ， but how could I archieve this?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make your `UIView` a `UIButton` and set the `UIViewController` as the target for touch up inside events.